# Subsections in reStructuredText

Tags: restructuredtext

I'm trying to write a document in reStructuredText, but am currently facing a problem.

I want the document to have a title, this is going to be centered, then immediately after that I want a subsection.

I tried doing the following

```
##############
Title
##############

+++++++++
Subtitle
+++++++++
content
```

But when I convert this to PDF, it makes both the title and subtitle centered.

Comment: I presume you mean that you want a section immediately after the title, having a subsection without a preceding section does not make a lot of sense. Assuming that this is the case, see my answer below.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the reStructuredText [quick start guide](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/user/rst/quickstart.html#document-title-subtitle) titles and sub-titles are specified as follows (emphasis mine):

> To indicate the document title in reStructuredText, use a **unique** adornment style at the beginning of the document. To indicate the document subtitle, use another **unique** adornment style immediately after the document title.

So in the reST example in the question, `Subtitle` is being formatted as a sub title and not a section heading since the adornment style used around `Subtitle` is not used anywhere else in the document. In the following, this adornment is used around two section headings, so is not unique and not treated as a subtitle:

```
##############
Document Title
##############

+++++++++++++++
Section 1 Title
+++++++++++++++

Section 1 content...

+++++++++++++++
Section 2 Title
+++++++++++++++

Section 2 content...
```

You can use [Pandoc](https://pandoc.org/try/) online (select "rst" in the "from" dropdown) to quickly try out some simple reStructuredText and test things like sub-titles vs. section titles.

**Edit**: Alternatively you could put some text between your title and section heading (like an abstract, for example).

P.s. I tend you use adornments above and below a heading to indicate a document title and sub-title and a single adornment below a heading to indicate a (sub-)section title. This makes it easy to see what I intended to be my title/sub-title. For example:

```
==============
Document title
==============
-----------------
Document subtitle
-----------------

Section
=======

Sub-section
-----------
etc.
```

Comment: Exactly what I was missing, more sections. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I found it helpful. Just to add. I also found this page : http://sphinx-doc.org/rest.html#sections which describes a Python convention for choice of adornment. It says: 
    # with overline, for parts;
    * with overline, for chapters;
    =, for sections;
    -, for subsections;
    ^, for subsubsections;
    ", for paragraphs;

Comment: What if all your heading / title / subtitle styles are unique, because you have a short document with only one chapter for example? How does it distinguish between heading and title / subtitle then?

Comment: Beware, the second link in this answer links to a potential malware site. It needs to be removed.

Comment: @v2v1 Link changed, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's quite natural to have a subsection start immediately under a section heading, as in

MY THINGS

My First Thing

...

My Second Thing

...

A work-around I found by trial and error is to put "\ " (backslash-space) as null content between the section heading and the subsection heading. With rst2html this has the desired effect without introducing any unwanted space.

Comment: The empty paragraph is a nice trick. (Note that a comment does not help.) In your example, however, it is not required as the "My Second Thing" heading disambiguates "My First Thing".